# UITextField with "clear' button size on begin editing

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have a UITextField with a clear button and I place it inside a vertical Stack View with leading alignment. When the editing starts, the field has the size without the clear button taking into account, so the text scrolls left. As soon as any character is added, the field corrects its size. I don't want to fix the field width, as I like this behaviour—when you always have the clear button at the end of the text.

The function below corrects the size, but the clear button appears only after the text field changes:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
        textField.sizeToFit()
    }
}
```

Any idea how to correct this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify your question. I don't understand what the two states of the text view size are. Possible to add screen shots?

Comment: The first state, when the field shows text. It has some intrinsic size. The second state — you start editing, taping inside. At this event, when the text becomes editable, the clear button appears. But the size of the text field remains the same as intrinsic size before, so, as the clear button needs some space too, the text of the field scrolls left. As soon as you start typing, the field changes its size properly and the stack view layouts everything.

Comment: As soon as I wrote you about intrinsic size, I decided to try: func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        
        textField.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        
    }. And it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}
```